# Jquery array from arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to make new array of string elements, from elements in one default array and other arrays i way like this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>A canvas animation example</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 20px;
            font-family: arial, verdana, helvetica;
            background: #fff;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 140%;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #036;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        canvas {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        pre {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            background: rgb(238,238,238);
            border: 1px dashed #666;
            padding: 15px 20px;
            margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
<h1>A canvas example</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <canvas class=re1g width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re2g width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re3g width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re1p width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re2p width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re3p width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re1b width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re2b width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re3b width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re1y width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re2y width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=re3y width=110 height=110></canvas>
    </li>
    <li>
        <canvas class=ci1g width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci2g width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci3g width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci1p width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci2p width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci3p width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci1b width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci2b width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci3b width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci1y width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci2y width=110 height=110></canvas>
        <canvas class=ci3y width=110 height=110></canvas>
    </li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function() {//on DOM ready
            // ===================
            var avaibleColors = [
                '#00C8A8','#75B520','#00CD25',
                '#FF63F6','#FF66B3','#DA73FF',
                '#978AFF','#00B5DE','#CF992C',
                '#CF992C','#FF795F','#C38628'
                ]; 

            var squareCol = [
                're1g','re2g','re3g',
                're1p','re2p','re3p',
                're1b','re2b','re3b',
                're1y','re2y','re3y'
                ];

            var circleCol = [
                'ci1g','ci2g','ci3g',
                'ci1p','ci2p','ci3p',
                'ci1b','ci2b','ci3b',
                'ci1y','ci2y','ci3y'
                ];

            var squareObj = [];
            var circleObj = [];
            var obj;

            $.each(squareCol, function(i, val){
                obj = {};
                obj[val] = avaibleColors[i];
                squareObj.push(obj);
            });

            $.each(circleCol, function(i, val){
                obj = {};
                obj[val] = avaibleColors[i];
                circleObj.push(obj);
            });
            // ===================
            $.each(squareObj, function(reColor, cValue) {
                    var canvasClass = $('canvas.'+reColor+'');
                    if(canvasClass != null) {
                        $.each(canvasClass, function(){
                            var ctx = this.getContext('2d');
                            ctx.save();
                            ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
                            ctx.fillStyle = cValue;
                            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
                            ctx.lineTo(90, 20);
                            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(90, 20, 90, 20);
                            ctx.lineTo(90, 90);
                            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(90, 90, 90, 90);
                            ctx.lineTo(20, 90);
                            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20, 90, 20, 90);
                            ctx.lineTo(20, 20);
                            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20, 20, 20, 20);
                            ctx.closePath();
                            ctx.fill();
                            ctx.stroke();
                            ctx.restore();
                        });
                    }// end of if
            console.log(reColor+' '+cValue);
            });
            // ===================
            $.each(circleObj, function(ciColor, cValue) {
                    var canvasClass = $('canvas.'+ciColor+'');
                    if(canvasClass != null) {
                        $.each(canvasClass, function(){
                            var ctx = this.getContext('2d');
                            ctx.save();
                            ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
                            ctx.fillStyle = cValue;
                            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.arc(55, 55, 45, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                            ctx.closePath();
                            ctx.fill();
                            ctx.stroke();
                            ctx.restore();
                        });
                    }// end of if
            });
            // ===================
            });
        })(jQuery)
    </script>
</body>
```

Simpler example:

```
var i_array = ['word1','word2','word3']; //array of n elements
var ii_array = ['text1','text2','text3']; //array of n elements
var iii_array = ['string1','string2','string3']; //array of n elements

//here is what I need:

var iv = ['text1':'word1','text2':'word2','text3':'word3'];
var v = ['string1':'word1','string2':'word2','string3':'word3'];

//To use in

$.each(iv, function(a,b){
  //do something with a,b
});

$.each(v, function(a,b){
  //do something with a,b
});
```

How to make pars of elements in new array, and use in drawing canvas..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple for loop should be able to do this:

```
for (x in i_array){
    iv[ii_array[x]] = i_array[x];
    v[iii_array[x]] = i_array[x];
}
```

See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/NdN9u/).

### UPDATED TO SOLVE REAL PROBLEM

Your code was messed up in a few places.  See working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/gfUXM/).

First of all, you don't need to create new arrays.  Just use the index of your circleCol or squareCol arrays to pull the color values from the availableColors array.

Like this:

```
$.each(squareCol, function(index, className) {
    cValue = avaibleColors[index];
    var canvasClass = '.'+className;
...
```

Second, you don't need to check if your canvasClass variable is null, because $.each() will pull each value of the array and no more; therefore, it will always pull a value for canvasClass, which in your case is the array key.

If anything you should use `if (canvas.getContext){`  as described in the [MDN canvas tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial%3ABasic_usage#Checking_for_support).

Hope this helps.  I kind of entirely redid the script, so I can't say exactly where the problem was.  I know that it was difficult to get the combined arrays to work with the $.each() functions.

### The problem was:

$.each() didn't work on the combined arrays.  It did, however, work, if you used a for...in... loop.  See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/heYke/).

Notice that you get nothing in console or in an alert if you tried to get the values from squareObj or circleObj.  I think it's because it turned into an object.  But I'm not familiar with this, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: This works, however you shouldn't use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over arrays.

Comment: Scroll down to the yellow block in the MDN page I linked to. Basically, `for...in` doesn't visit elements in any defined order, (which probably doesn't matter in this case). Just something to look out for.

Comment: yes but when use it in function for drawing canvas it`s not working

Comment: @Art-of-Life The answer to your question does not solve your problem.  I will give you a solution to your problem; give me a second.

Comment: I updated upper code, i hope i replace values the right way.. as ShankarSangoli sujested but nop.. no drawing...

Comment: @Art-of-Life Check out this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/gfUXM/) and updated answer.  Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @bozdoz YEA... you are the man.... I want to bay you a beer... or juce.. ccc.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should represent them as an array of object key/value pair. Try this.

```
var i_array = ['word1','word2','word3']; //array of n elements
var ii_array = ['text1','text2','text3']; //array of n elements
var iii_array = ['string1','string2','string3']; //array of n elements


var iv = [];
var v = [];
var obj;

$.each(i_array, function(i, val){
   obj = {};obj[ii_array[i]] = val;
   iv.push(obj);
   obj = {};obj[iii_array[i]] = val;
   v.push(obj);
});

//Now you can use iv and v inside the loop here

$.each(iv, function(a,b){
  //do something with a,b
});

$.each(v, function(a,b){
  //do something with a,b
});
```

**EDIT:**

I just looked at what you are doing in the fiddle you created. You don'have to create new arrays containing key/value pairs. You can easily use the existing arrays and work with them.

I have created a working demo using the existing arrays take a look.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tHePB/2/)**

Comment: I updated upper code, i hope i replace values the right way.. Please help

Comment: @Art-of-Life - I didn't get you.

Comment: ok I post the code on jsfiddle but in harder way.. i just want to make it more simpler and custom frendly http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/NdN9u/

Comment: That is wrong use of array you should create an object and store in array.

Comment: here is working exampel http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/NdN9u/
But in don`t want way... I want to generate array from diferent sets of arrays and in specific vay key, value

Comment: How than should i do.. this is only that is working... http://jsfiddle.net/ehjBL/

Comment: I used your sugestion still no canvas... here is what yous sugested http://jsfiddle.net/tHePB/1/

Comment: no still not working... I made a link to all code.. http://jsfiddle.net/ArtofLife/u9d9d/2/

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. I have created a working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tHePB/2/

Answer (score 0):

I know I will face problems by answering you, but I give you a try :)
Try this way:

```
var i_array = ['word1','word2','word3']; //array of n elements
var ii_array = ['text1','text2','text3']; //array of n elements
var iii_array = ['string1','string2','string3']; //array of n elements

//here is what I need:

//var iv = ['text1':'word1','text2':'word2','text3':'word3'];
//var v = ['string1':'word1','string2':'word2','string3':'word3'];

var iv = new Array();
var v = new Array();
for (var x=0; x<i_array.length; x++)
{
    iv[ii_array[x]] = i_array[x];
    v[iii_array[x]] = i_array[x];
}

// Test if everything went right        
for (var key in iv)
{
    console.log(key+'|'+iv[key]);
}

for (var key in v)
{
    console.log(key+'|'+v[key]);
}
```

**EDITED (A)**

I think I got you :)

Two ways to solve your problem:

1)

```
var i_array = ['word1','word2','word3']; //array of n elements
var ii_array = ['text1','text2','text3']; //array of n elements
var iii_array = ['string1','string2','string3']; //array of n elements

var iv = new Array();
var v = new Array();
for (var x=0; x<i_array.length; x++)
{
    iv[ii_array[x]] = i_array[x];
    v[iii_array[x]] = i_array[x];
}

var iv_indexed = new Array();;
for (var k in iv)
{
    iv_indexed.push(k);
    iv_indexed[k] = iv[k];
}

var v_indexed = new Array();;
for (var k in v)
{
    v_indexed.push(k);
    v_indexed[k] = v[k];
}

// Let's try it! :)
$.each(iv_indexed, function(a,b){
    var key = b;
    var value = iv_indexed[b];
    console.log(key+'|'+value);
});

$.each(v_indexed, function(a,b){
    var key = b;
    var value = v_indexed[b];
    console.log(key+'|'+value);
});
```

2)

```
var i_array = ['word1','word2','word3']; //array of n elements
var ii_array = ['text1','text2','text3']; //array of n elements
var iii_array = ['string1','string2','string3']; //array of n elements

iv = new Array();
v = new Array();
for (var x=0; x<i_array.length; x++)
{
    var key = ii_array[x];
    var value = i_array[x];

    var add = {};
    add[ii_array[x]] = i_array[x];
    iv.push( add );

    var add = {};
    add[iii_array[x]] = i_array[x];
    v.push( add );
}

// Let's try it! :)
$.each(iv, function(a,b){
    for (k in b)
    {
        var key = k;
        var value = b[k];
    }
    console.log(key+'|'+value);
});

$.each(v, function(a,b){
    for (k in b)
    {
        var key = k;
        var value = b[k];
    }
    console.log(key+'|'+value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i_array   = ['word1','word2','word3'],
    ii_array  = ['text1','text2','text3'],
    iii_array = ['string1','string2','string3'],
    iv = {},
    v  = {};

$.each(i_array, function(index, value){
    iv[ii_array[index]] = value;
    v[iii_array[index]] = value;
});
```